# Let $Y\sim\text{uniform}(0,1)$ and define $X=\min\{Y,1-Y\}$. What is the PDF of $X$?

Tags: probability

> Let $Y\sim\text{uniform}(0,1)$ and define $X=\min\{Y,1-Y\}$. What is the PDF of $X$?

**Thoughts:** I considered a case-by-case analysis, as in

$$\begin{split}P(X<x) & =P(Y<x\land Y<1/2)+P(1-Y<x\land Y>1/2) \\
 & =P(Y<x|Y<1/2)P(Y<1/2)+P(1-Y<x|Y>1/2)P(Y>1/2) \\
 & =2x(1/2)+2x(1/2)=2x\end{split}$$

Which is the CDF, hence the PDF is merely $f_X(x)=2$.

**Question:** Am I right? This seems incredible to me.

Comment: Sure, density is $2$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $0$ elsewhere,

Comment: Should not be surprising. If you look at your derivation, you will realize that either Y < 1/2 or > 1/2 and thus min will always lie in [0, 1/2] and it will be uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the cdf is correct but can be simplified. Let $0\lt x\le \frac{1}{2}$.  Then 
$X\le x$ if and only if $Y\le x$ or $Y\ge 1-x$. The intervals $[0,x]$  and $[1-x,1]$ each have length $x$.